# How to use audio/WebRtcAudioRecord rather than voiceengine/WebRtcAudioRecord

Tags: webrtc, audiorecord, android-audiorecord, webrtc-android, mediasoup

The WebRTC project has two WebRtcAudioRecord classes, one in the audio package, which is a new implementation, and another in the voiceengine package, which is an old implementation.

I don't know how to switch between the two implementations. Upon debugging, it was found that the WebRtcAudioRecord class in the voiceengine package is always being used. Is it possible to switch to using the one in the audio package?